# Coded UI Test recording new test overwrites UIMap.Designer.cs changes

Tags: c#, .net, automated-tests

I am recording an Coded UI test for successful log in scenario. After pulling up 'Coded UI Test builder', I recorded following steps.

1. Launch exe
2. Click on form which triggers some animation on page
       and after 5-6 seconds I am given an option to 'Register' or 'Login'
3. I clicked on 'Login'(uILoginButton) button and do successful login.

When I try to play back this test, it crashed at step no 3 saying, 'Can not find UI element named 'btnLogin'

So I navigate to UIMap.Designer.cs file and added below line of code before button click.

```
uILoginButton.WaitForControlExist();
```

My recorded method inside 'UIMap.Designer.cs' looks some thing like this

```
/// <summary>
/// DoLogin
/// </summary>
public void DoLogin()
{
    #region Variable Declarations
    WpfButton uILoginButton= this.UIMPortPodGUIWindow.UIItemCustom7.UIContinueButton;
    #endregion
    uILoginButton.WaitForControlExist(100);

    // Click 'Continue' button
    Mouse.Click(uILoginButton, new Point(191, 42));
}
```

After this I played back this test and I was happy to see everything worked fine.
Then I start recording second test and after completing recording I realized that recording has overwritten my previous changes to `UIMap.Designer.cs` i.e. below line was missing

```
uILoginButton.WaitForControlExist();
```

I know it should go inside 'UIMap.cs' but don't know how to partially declare DoLogin() method in two classes.

Which is the best place to add our custom code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never put code in a `.Designer.cs` unless you don't care about it being randomly lost.

In this situation what I would normally do is copy the code from the autogenerated DoLogin and make my own method inside `UIMap.cs` (not `UIMap.Designer.cs`) that had the custom steps.

```
public partial class UIMap
{
    public void DoLoginWithWait()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WpfButton uILoginButton = this.UIMPortPodGUIWindow.UIItemCustom7.UIContinueButton;
        #endregion
        uILoginButton.WaitForControlExist(100);

        // Click 'Continue' button
        Mouse.Click(uILoginButton, new Point(191, 42));
    }
}
```

The empty `UIMap.cs` the program makes is for the exact situation you are in. `UIMap.cs` will not be overwritten during the recording of new steps so you can safely put your code in there.

---

**EDIT**

After poking around a little bit further I found there is a button to make this even easier. From the `UIMap.uitest` editor click the [image] button (or Ctrl+Alt+C) this will take the method out of the designer and put it in the `UIMap.cs` file, you can then edit the method in safety without worrying about rebuilt designer files overwriting your changes.